# JQuery Mobile popup window under footer and header

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, popup

I have a popup using jquery mobile in ios 7.0.4, but it appears under the header and footer, it should be on top, why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: We can't see your sample code. Please repost it.

Comment: I wish I can provide sample code, its a very complicate backbone view that opens up another backbone view as popup etc. dont have the source code. I just wonder if there are any guidance if anyone have encountered similar problem before. popup does contain google map, and it works before 7.0.3 and query mobile 1.4 beta

Comment: I correct myself, it works on ios 7.0.4 with query mobile 1.4 alpha 2, but not working on jquery mobile 1.4 beta 1. so something must be broken

Comment: It's better to wait until 1.4 is officially released.